# Using a database in a Windows application

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, windows, kinect

I am developing a Microsoft Kinect game (for Windows) using C# and I need a local database to store information about players and their progress as well as more detailed information on their points and accuracy. I have never used a database within a Windows application and I was looking for some advice on how to do so. I have been trying to use SQL Server because it lets me create a database within Visual Studio. I have been unable to find many resources on how to interact with the database from within the C# application.

I really know very little about SQL Server so I do not know if it is the right choice for what I need. Does anyone have a suggestion for what sort of database system to use? Can you point me in the direction of some good resources/examples on how to do what I need to do?

Thanks so much!

Edit: I should also mention that I do have experience working with SQL.

Comment: I know you probably hate to hear this, but serialized XML may also work, too depending on how much information you're storing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are other, more portable, solutions such as [SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) and [SQL Server Compact Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx) which do not require a separate server installation and are more easily accessed and distributed from within a standalone desktop application.

The usage can be largely compared to an external SQL server and/or Linq to SQL so the actual implementation should not be that hard.

Some interesting links:

- [How to: Deploy a SQL Server Compact 4.0 Database with an Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [An Introduction to SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/3cf852/an-introduction-to-sql-server-compact-edition-sqlce-4-0/)

As mentioned in another comment, a simple serialized XML file might also be enough for your use. It's fast, easy and if you don't need to perform any actual database operations but simply save and load everything then it might be more efficient.

Comment: SQL Server Compact Edition sounds great. Do you know of any resources that better explain how to use and interface with it in C#?

Comment: I've edited my post and included some links which I've used in the past.

Comment: How would you like to do it? The minimal level of plumbing between you and the database would be ADO.NET, as accessed through the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace. At the other end of the scale are ORMs like [EF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) or [nHibernate](http://nhforge.org/); and in between there's [LINQ-to-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Look into using a SQLDatasource and relevant tutorials.  This will give you an easy way to get up and running without an intimate knowledge of SQL.  Once you have the datasource setup and 'bound' to your database, you can use this to connect your controls (grids,labels,textboxes ect.) to it.

Check this out:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w34BDhDPEEQ

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the fully fledged SQL Server. SQL Server Compact Edition is more appropriate, or there's also SQLite for a non-Microsoft option.

The easiest way to interact with a database from C# is Entity Framework, which ships with .NET 4.5 or is downloadable as a nuget package for .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.

A different, non-relational-database option would be [DB4O](http://www.db4o.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)

```
var player = db.Players.Where(x => x.playerId = id);
var points = player.points;

points =+ 100;
db.SaveChanges();
```

You could also write [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations against the tables if you don't want to use an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)

Answer (score 0):

Basicly you will have to make a database with a table, using the GUI of Visual Studio.

Then where necessary in the code, you will have to create a connection with the database using a connectionstring. Then you will have to insert an SQL command using the SQLCommand class and execute it. This requires some knowledge about the SQL syntax, but just search what kind of command you want specifically now and in time you will get the hang of it. Don't forget to close the connection to the database when you are ready with writing or reading data.

I hope this gives the main idea.

Edit: Oh and for this kind of database SQL Server Compact will be enough.